# Is it better to wait for Snapper to finish before rebooting?

Tags: opensuse, btrfs, snapshot

I run various openSUSE systems with btrfs file systems.  On these setups, openSUSE uses [Snapper](https://en.opensuse.org/openSUSE:Snapper_Tutorial) to manage filesystem snapshots.  Every time I finish updating the system using Zypper or the YaST software management tool, htop and iotop show that the Snapper process is busy doing its thing (presumably creating a new snapshot).  This activity can last for several minutes.

Sometimes after updating, it's necessary to reboot the system (for example, to load a new kernel).  When such a reboot is necessary, is it better to wait for Snapper to finish?  That is, are there any downsides to *not* waiting?  Will this prevent Snapper from creating a snapshot, or will it pick up from where it left off once I reboot?

Comment: I'm a bit baffled by the downvote. If the question is off-topic or otherwise inappropriate, please prove further details so that I can move or revise it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `snapper` is doing (`strace` could tell you if you attach it for a moment) but it is not creating the snapshot because that takes only a moment and would not be shown as `snapper` I/O anyway.

It may be `snapper` comparing snapshots.